# Dolphin (file manager) keyboard shortcuts config-file location

Tags: configuration, filemanager, dolphin, location

Does anyone know where Dolphin keeps the keyboard shortcuts stored?
I've already looked into the config-files in `~/.kde/share/config/`, there's a `dolphinrc` there, but the saved shortcuts are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Could you elaborate about what you mean by shortcuts in the context of Dolphin?

Comment: the keybindings for navigating dolphin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc`.

The way I dug that out: I made a shortcut with `Meta+Ctrl+B` to report a bug. After that, I used `find` to find which file in my home folder was modified as a result.

[image: Configure shortcuts]

Here's part of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE kpartgui SYSTEM 'kpartgui.dtd'>
<kpartgui version="14" name="dolphin">
... lots of deleted stuff ...
  <Action shortcut="Meta+Ctrl+B" name="help_report_bug"/>
 </ActionProperties>
</kpartgui>
```

Comment: well done!
the path was different for me, but the filename was the same

Comment: I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 with `kubuntu-backports` enabled.